# EXCEL: COUNTIFS function with criteria on referenced dropdown counting the ANY criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have brands A,B,C,D,E located in separate worksheets with similar columned tables (Branch, Ownership, Status, City/Town).

I need the formulated cell to count the number of Branch per brand based on the referenced dropdown

I can count it using this  (SUMMARY are the tables for the referenced dropdown)

=COUNTIFS(BRAND[OWNERSHIP], SUMMARY_OWNERSHIP[OWNERSHIP], BRAND[STATUS], BRAND_STATUS[STATUS], BRAND[CITY/TOWN], SUMMARY_CITYTOWN[CITY/TOWN]

However, it won't count the ANY criteria. I need it to include it in the countifs logic when I select ANY (e.g. Ownership) count the branches regardless if company-owned or franchised

[image]

[image]

P.S. Sorry for the poor English, ain't my native language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to supply a criteria array of all the available ownership, status and/or city/town options if OWNERSHIP is *Any*. It's probably easier to do this with a wildcard e.g. `*`.

```
=COUNTIFS(BRAND[OWNERSHIP], IF(SUMMARY_OWNERSHIP[OWNERSHIP]]="any", "*", SUMMARY_OWNERSHIP[OWNERSHIP]]),
          BRAND[STATUS], IF(BRAND_STATUS[STATUS]]="any", "*", BRAND_STATUS[STATUS]]),
          BRAND[CITY/TOWN], IF(SUMMARY_CITYTOWN[CITY/TOWN]="any", "*", SUMMARY_CITYTOWN[CITY/TOWN]))
```

Comment: Can you elaborate how to do that?

Comment: Are you telling me that the formula I supplied above doesn't work?

Comment: I apologize, I missed something. It definitely worked great! Thanks